# FHIR: is there a private entities adoption problem?

Tags: hl7-fhir

While the public hospitals are trying to adopt FHIR as soon as possible this seems to not be the case for private entities. I heard that private entities are less likely to adopt FHIR due to the cost of transition and the fear of losing clients. I understand the cost reason, but the other one doesn't seems right. I chose a clinic based on the doctor I want to go to and the medical insurance I have. I don't know about HIPAA but in Europe the GDPR gives you the right to ask any entity to provide you the medical history in an interoperable format. This doesn't necessary means FHIR, but rather xml or json.

What do you think about this? What are the other problems and how do you tackle it?

Comment: I have a feeling this type of question is best discussed at http://community.fhir.org :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adoption patterns of FHIR vary from country to country and discipline to discipline.  They're influenced by a bunch of factors:

- are there regulations or government initiatives requiring the use of FHIR? requiring the use of a different standard?  requiring interoperability at all?
- are there business drivers that encourage interoperability (e.g. "My patients want to have their data on their phone" or "I can't keep up with the customization demands, I need people to be able to write plug-ins for my system"
- are there already interoperability solutions in place and, if so, do they work?

These don't typically break down into public/private but in some countries they might.

Certainly there can be pushback against interoperability because of concern it may make it easier for patients to move elsewhere.  That's one of the reasons for regulations such as GDPR or the data blocking rules in the U.S.  Such regulations help, but if the desire isn't there to make sharing easy, then the tendency will be to meet the barest letter of the laws and to avoid as much as possible supporting their spirit.

One of FHIR's advantages is that it reduces the technical cost of interoperability.  It's also spawned lots of examples of successful interoperability which proponents can point to.  Both factors help to lessen the excuse for inaction of "it's too hard/expensive".  However, for those who want excuses, there are always others to be found...